# Unexpected values on X axis when using morris line charts

Tags: morris.js

I am using morris charts for represent my data and its work fine except some unexpected values for X aixs in line charts. following is the json encode script that I am using and Date is my X key.

```js
[{"Date":"5","Uria":"2.22140","TSP":"1.22140","MOP":"1.22140","TDM":"2.22140"},
{"Date":"6","Uria":"14.79140","TSP":"8.43690","MOP":"6.68960","TDM":"6.72480"},
{"Date":"7","Uria":"3.48100","TSP":"3.14000","MOP":"2.21700","TDM":"0.12000"}]
```

For the above data the line chart and bar are nicely drawn. But the problem is for line chart X axis I got some values like below when the data range is small.

1905-01 1905-03 1905-05 1905-07  1905-09 1905-11 1906-01  1906-03 1906-05 1906-07 1906-09  1906-11 1907-01

I think it is some sort of dividing the axis to draw the chart. But my problem is I can't understand where they come from.Please help to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the property `parseTime: false` to receive the right results. Your Date is parsed as a date. Date 5 appears to be rendered as 1905. Date 6 is rendered as 1906. Between 1905 and 1906, Morris.js is populating minor axis and therefore you see 1905-01, -03, -05, -07, -09 and -11.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Morris.js Area Chart Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="area-example"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
Morris.Area({
  element: 'area-example',
  data: [  
    {  
        "Date":"5",
        "Uria":"2.22140",
        "TSP":"1.22140",
        "MOP":"1.22140",
        "TDM":"2.22140"
    },
    {  
        "Date":"6",
        "Uria":"14.79140",
        "TSP":"8.43690",
        "MOP":"6.68960",
        "TDM":"6.72480"
    },
    {  
        "Date":"7",
        "Uria":"3.48100",
        "TSP":"3.14000",
        "MOP":"2.21700",
        "TDM":"0.12000"
    }
  ],
  xkey: 'Date',
  ykeys: ['Uria', 'TSP', 'MOP', 'TDM'],
  labels: ['Uria', 'TSP', 'MOP', 'TDM'],
  parseTime: false
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/e8jbeLzv/1/#run, or you could use jsbin.com and try it out.

Comment: Thanks zedfoxus. Your answer is very clear and works fine.